# Removing silkscreen paint which overlaps copper padding after printing

Tags: pcb, design

I am new to advanced PCB printing and, as it turns out, my PCB printing vendor prints the silkscreen white text over some copper padding according to my design, which i don't know that would happen. Is there any way to fix this issue, Should i try using rubbing alcohol, and would that damage the copper padding?

Here is what it looks like
[image: it's the one below the orange smudge]

Comment: That's not necessarily the vendor's fault, they're just manufacturing what your gerbers specified... It would have been nice of them to warn you about this, but they have no real obligation to do so. Be sure to check your gerbers before sending anything to the fab.

Comment: yes i know it is my design's fault, i don't know that they're going to literally take the whole thing and print the whole layers, like i said, im new to pcb designing, im only used to printing with copper layers

Comment: I don't think rubbing alcohol will do *anything*. I think the chemical composition of the silkscreen is pretty close to that of the soldermask – and you can't wipe it off without removing the soldermask. Not that there's many things that could dissolve that, to begin with – I don't even think acetone does.

Comment: I think at this point: if you can wait, order new boards for cheap. You could straighten up/shorten quite a few traces in your layout, anyway ;) and, in 99% of cases, you'd want a ground plane, so add one.

Comment: To add to what others have said, I don't know what software you're using but I know that kicad at least has an option to automatically remove silkscreen from the places where there's no soldermask. Whatever software you're using will probably have a similar setting available.

Comment: Most PCB fab shops will remove silkscreen overlapping the pads, or at least ask if they should remove it. Looks like you found the one that doesn't. :-) It's a good idea to check the gerber files in a gerber viewer before sending them to the fab shop. Turn off all layers, but the soldermask and silk screen for the top layer. If they overlap you should adjust the silkscreen. Repeat for the bottom layer if it has silk screen.

Comment: Looks like the pads are all tin-plated, so you might find that if you heat the accessible part of the pads with a soldering iron and add a little solder, the tin plate below the silkscreen will melt and allow the silkscreen to just slide off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only three things I can think to try:

a) Try gently scraping it off with a scalpel

b) Try fine emery cloth to rub it off

c) Ignore it, and see whether you can still get a reasonable connection when soldering

Comment: a fiberglass burnishing pen should also work. That's probably the most convenient and accurate way. Also works to remove solder mask so you can solder to traves for rework.